# Mysqli Segmentation fault

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, segmentation-fault

Today I've tried to install Xdebug, then Netbeans, Netbeans chrome extension etc. and suddenly my PHP script that creates new mysqli object doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','mysqlsamplepassword', 'Test_Database');
?>
```

When login credentials are wrong, I receive proper warning, but when they are OK web browser shows `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error. In apache.log I can find:

```
[Thu Jul 31 20:54:24.658848 2014] [core:notice] [pid 9797] AH00051: child pid 9814 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Based on other stackoverflow questions covering this matter, I did backtracing by gdb:

```
(gdb) attach 9797
(...)
0x00007ff3d584fc13 in __select_nocancel ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: There's no such file or directory
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007ff3d584fc13 in __select_nocancel ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
No locals.
#1  0x00007ff3d5d66d65 in apr_sleep ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ff3d663a401 in ap_wait_or_timeout ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ff3d2e92076 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ff3d663998e in ap_run_mpm ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ff3d6633166 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb)
```

Unfortunatelly reinstalling apache2, php5-mysql didn't help. PDO extension works, but all my scripts are based on mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed latest php (5.6.0RC3, as I used development preview version) with this configure command:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd
```

Unfortunatelly it didn't swap old php5 module. In `etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load` I found what php module is loaded:

`LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`

I changed this line to newely compilled libphp5.so path:

`LoadModule php5_module /home/YourUsername/php-5.6.0RC3/libs/libphp5.so`

but you can also overwrite this file to avert mess.